# Parsing pipe separated value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have a **User_Role** column in one of my table, which has pipe separated values like

```
guest|user_Admin|user_guest
user_Admin|guest
guest|user_guest|user_Admin
user_guest|user_Admin
user_Admin
```

I have to get the roles from the above column, which has ***Admin*** in it. 
I don't want the entire row which has Admin.

For example, if the column data is *guest|user_guest|user_Admin*, the query should return only *user_Admin* instead of entire value.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You could just write a case statement like `CASE WHEN User_Role LIKE '%user_Admin%' THEN 'user_Admin' END` or if you only want users with user_Admin as a user role then, `SELECT 'user_Admin' FROM myTable WHERE User_Role LIKE '%user_Admin%'` or something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search value in column which is pipe separated in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767077/search-value-in-column-which-is-pipe-separated-in-sql)

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the value. I want to derive it from the data.

Comment: What do you mean, "derive it from the data?" If there can be different sorts of "admin" roles then you'll need to do a recursive cte over the column to split the values (or just apply a split function) and get whatever the "admin" role is for that user. If it's always going to be "user_admin" though, "hard coding" it is better. The REAL solution, though, is to change your table structure so that you don't have to parse the string.... Add a different line for each user role OR create a separate table with the individual roles...

Comment: @turbo88 I have got a solution for you. Took me a while but I got it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to tell you what you should be doing... Normalise your table.

If the table in question is a user role table, then split your user_role column into single values. If it's part of a larger table with other columns, then you should use a separate table to store the user role information. I would also suggest assigning different levels to each value so you don't have to parse strings at all.

For example, have a user_roles table like

```
CREATE TABLE userRoles (userID INT, userRole INT);
```

... and then have a roles table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Roles (userRole INT IDENTITY(1, 1), roleDescription VARCHAR(255), roleLevel INT);
INSERT Roles (roleDescription, roleLevel) VALUES ('guest', 1), ('user_guest', 2), ('user_Admin', 3);
```

... this way, you can find admin roles by doing joins and looking for level 3 rather than parsing strings. If your tables are small anyway, no big deal, but the bigger your tables get, the more costly parsing strings is going to be. With proper indexing, this is going to be the fastest way to retrieve whatever data you need while making it easy to change data if necessary (need to change the role name? No problem... Edit the roleDescription in the Roles table).

But failing that, here's a couple solutions you can consider...

```
declare @1 table (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), User_Role varchar(255));
insert @1 (User_Role) values ('guest|hello_Kitty_Admin|user_guest'),('user_Admin_zzz|guest'),('guest|user_guest|greatest_admin_of_all_time'),('user_guest|user_Admin2'),('user_Admin'),('regular_user');
with t as (
    select id, user_role, left(User_Role, charindex('admin', User_Role) + isnull(nullif(charindex('|', substring(User_Role, charindex('admin', User_Role), len(User_Role))), 0) - 2, len(User_Role))) zzz
    from @1)
select id, isnull(right(zzz, isnull(nullif(charindex('|', reverse(zzz)), 0) - 1, len(zzz))), user_role) adminrole
from t;
```

... all the above is doing is parsing your user_role column, finding where admin is and getting everything between the line braces for that value (if one doesn't exist, it just returns the user_role in full)

```
declare @2 table(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), User_Role varchar(255));
insert @2 (User_Role) values ('guest|hello_Kitty_Admin|user_guest'),('user_Admin_zzz|guest'),('guest|user_guest|greatest_admin_of_all_time'),('user_guest|user_Admin2'),('user_Admin'),('regular_user');
with cte as (
    select id, user_role, substring(user_role, 1, isnull(nullif(charindex('|', user_role), 0) - 1, len(user_role))) roles, nullif(charindex('|', user_role), 0) cindex, 1 L
    from @2
    union all
    select id, user_role, substring(user_role, cindex+1, isnull(nullif(charindex('|', user_role, cindex+1), 0) - 1 - cindex, len(user_role))), nullif(charindex('|', user_role, cindex+1), 0), L + 1
    from cte
    where cindex is not null)
select id, max(isnull(x.y, user_role)) adminrole
from cte t
outer apply (
    select min(roles) over (partition by len(roles))
    from cte
    where id = t.id
    and roles like '%admin%') x(y)
group by id, x.y
order by id;
```

... this is doing the same thing as the other one with a different method.

Or you could use a cursor similar to the other answer, with slight modifications.

But really, normalise!

Answer (score -1):

This should work. It uses a cursor to process each role.

**--- UPDATE ---**

Updated the cursor processing to cover many edge cases.

```
DECLARE @roles varchar(1000), @ADMININDEX int, @STARTINDEX int, @ENDINDEX int, @TEMP varchar(1000)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT roles
FROM test

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @roles
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    --Do something with Id here
    SET @ADMININDEX = CHARINDEX('Admin',@roles)
    IF (@ADMININDEX > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ADMININDEX += 5
        SET @TEMP = CHARINDEX('|', SUBSTRING(@roles, @ADMININDEX, LEN(@roles)))
        IF @TEMP = 0
            SET @ENDINDEX = LEN(@roles) + 1
        ELSE
            SET @ENDINDEX = @TEMP - 1 + @ADMININDEX
        SET @roles = SUBSTRING(@roles, 0, @ENDINDEX)
        SET @STARTINDEX = LEN(@roles) - CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(@roles)) + 2
        IF (@STARTINDEX>@ADMININDEX)
            PRINT @roles
        ELSE
            PRINT SUBSTRING(@roles, @STARTINDEX, @ENDINDEX)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @roles
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: this technically would only work if a user's role was like 'xyz_admin'. if a user's role were like 'admin_xyz' you wouldn't get the correct result. it also wouldn't work for a user that doesn't have an admin role (if that's important).

Comment: @ZLK These cases are extremely easy to bypass with some minor modifications. I just laid out a foundation based on the sample provided.

Comment: A reason as to why the downvote was given would be helpful.